# looking for fastest way string to JSONObject in Android

Tags: java, android, json

I used to use new JSONObject(string) to convert string to JSONObject. however, it is too slow performance-wise. Anybody have the faster solution?

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [Jackson](http://jackson.codehaus.org/). They claim to be faster than any other Java JSON parser. It also parses the data in a stream, lowering memory consumption.

Comment: But for multiple thread accessing, ObjectMapper might be slower than

Answer (score 0):

I've used Gson with some good success: http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/